# Making Parallax Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, parallax

I'm currently working on a site where I have a parallax effect on an image, that is positioned with a fixed height. When changes in screen size occur, the fixed height of course is changed, and that ruins the effect. I know I can use media screens to fix this, but I'm unsure of what heights I need to define and if there is possibly an easier way to position my image for this.

I'm using stellar.js if that helps at all.
The image is positioned with:

```
    position: fixed;
    top:-2050%;
    left:25%;
    margin-top:-3%;
    margin-left: -24%;
    z-index:1;
```

Comment: can you add your markup?

Comment: With what Phlume said, you have no real markup that we can help you with. But what I'm thinking is that the position of parallax images should be relative to the image size, right? So use javascript, scale the image to the pagewidth, and then position your image in accordance to its scale. Again, it'll help us help you when you show us your HTML.